# How to have multiple positional options with boost::program_options

Tags: c++, boost

I write a program receiving two list of files as arguments:

```
$ program --to-list-A a b c --to-list-B d e f g
```

I would like to allow other options to appear anywhere on the command line and to keep these files grouped in the last occurence of the list arguments :

```
$ program --to-list-A a b c --to-list-B d e f --some-option g
```

Both command lines should produce a list `A` with `a`, `b` and `c` and a list `B` with `d`, `e`, `f` and `g`.

Is this possible to achieve this with `boost::program_options`? So far I could not manage to add `g` to `B` in the second case. Here is the test code I use :

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/program_options.hpp>

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  boost::program_options::options_description command_line_options;

  command_line_options.add_options()
    ( "some-option", "boolean option" )
    ( "to-list-A",
      boost::program_options::value< std::vector< std::string > >()
      ->multitoken() )
    ( "to-list-B",
      boost::program_options::value< std::vector< std::string > >()
      ->multitoken() );

  boost::program_options::positional_options_description positional_options;
  positional_options.add( "to-list-A", -1 );

  boost::program_options::variables_map arguments;
  boost::program_options::store
    ( boost::program_options::command_line_parser( argc, argv )
      .options( command_line_options ).positional( positional_options ).run(),
      arguments );

  std::cout << "in A:";

  if ( arguments.count( "to-list-A" ) != 0 )
    for ( const auto& s
            : arguments[ "to-list-A" ].as< std::vector< std::string > >() )
      std::cout << ' ' << s;

  std::cout << '\n';

  std::cout << "in B:";

  if ( arguments.count( "to-list-B" ) != 0 )
    for ( const auto& s
            : arguments[ "to-list-B" ].as< std::vector< std::string > >() )
      std::cout << ' ' << s;

  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

**Edit**: I would like `to-list-A' to be implicit for the first files, i.e the following command line should place`a`,`b`and`c`in`A` too:

```
$ program a b c --to-list-B d e f --some-option g
```

Comment: You did try `positional_options.add( "to-list-B", -1 );`, right?

Comment: It would work if both list options are on the command line, but if I omit `to-list-A` then everything goes to `B` (see my edit). Moreover the documentation says that two calls to `add` with the value `-1` should not work: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/positional_opt_idp13499152.html#idp187622176-bb